# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: call revert exception

Tags: angular, solidity, web3js, angular12, moralis

Working with angular and moralis i get this error whenever i try to read any view function. Below is the function which returns the error

```
async contractBalance() {
    let options = {
      contractAddress: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      functionName: "investorCount",
      abi: ABI
    }
await Moralis.enableWeb3();
return await Moralis.executeFunction(options);}
```

Below is a link to my abi and function

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpbne99coinerm2/abi.ts?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sp26mrdpllghc6de63w9k/Document.docx?dl=0&rlkey=9fjrpc9s91wldbuq8mahdfuae

Github Repo
https://github.com/orajiakuchibuchi/ETH-INVEST

Here is a link to my repo, after login, using rinkeby network for metamask, navigate to the dashboard from the guide page after authentication. error is thrown in the dashboard page, blockchainService line 206

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @NiccolòFant 

Github Repo https://github.com/orajiakuchibuchi/ETH-INVEST

Here is a link to my repo, after login, using rinkeby network for metamask, navigate to the dashboard from the guide page after authentication. error is thrown in the dashboard page, blockchainService line 206

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `investorCount` is correctly formated?

It should look something like this.

```js
const ABI = [
 {
    inputs: [],
    name: "message",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "",
        type: "string",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "_newMessage",
        type: "string",
      },
    ],
    name: "setMessage",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  }
];

const readOptions = {
  contractAddress: "0xe...56",
  functionName: "message",
  abi: ABI
};

const message = await Moralis.executeFunction(readOptions);
console.log(message)
// -> "Hello World"
```

Comment: yes it is well formatted, here is a link to my abi and function 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpbne99coinerm2/abi.ts?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sp26mrdpllghc6de63w9k/Document.docx?dl=0&rlkey=9fjrpc9s91wldbuq8mahdfuae

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to read data you don't have to enable Web3.
Try something like this:

```
const ABI = [...]

const options = {
   address: "xxxx",
   function_name: "investorCount",
   abi: ABI
};

const res = await Moralis.Web3API.native.runContractFunction(options);
```

If you want give a look at Moralis [docs](https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/web3-sdk/native#runcontractfunction).

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.

Comment: https://github.com/orajiakuchibuchi/ETH-INVEST Here is a link to my repo, after login, using rinkeby network for metamask, navigate to dashboard from the guide page after authentication. error is thrown in the dashboard page, blockchainService line 206